# transforming html to csv with xmllint

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I'm parsing a html file successfully with xmllint but when I combine two or more xpath expressions I get only one occurrence and not all of them.

When I run the expressions separately I get something like this:

Expression:

`xmllint --html --xpath "//h3[contains(text(),'Rodada')]/../following-sibling::div//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')][2]/text()" 2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html 2>/dev/null`

Result:

```
&#13;
              Couto Pereira - Curitiba - PR
&#13;
              Aflitos - Recife - PE
&#13;
              Serra Dourada - Goiania - GO
&#13;
```

But when I combine the expressions:

```
prefix="//h3[contains(text(),'Rodada')]/../following-sibling::div"
```

`xmllint --html --xpath "normalize-space(concat($prefix//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')]/text(),';',$prefix//div[contains(@class,'pull-left')]//img/@title,';',$prefix//div[contains(@class,'pull-right')]//img/@title,';',$prefix//strong/span/text(),';',$prefix//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')][2]/text()))" 2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html 2>/dev/null`

Result:

> Sáb, 19/05/2012 18:30 - Jogo: 3 ;Palmeiras - SP;Portuguesa - SP;1 x 1; Pacaembu - Sao Paulo - SP

It works but stop at the first result. I can't make it parse all the file.

To run this example, you can download the html from here

```
curl https://www.cbf.com.br/futebol-brasileiro/competicoes/campeonato-brasileiro-serie-a/2012 --compressed > /tmp/2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html
```

Answer (score 1):

With any call to functions like `normalize-space` or `concat` in XPath 1.0, if you call it on an argument being a node-set only the value of the first node in the node-set is used.

In XPath 2 and later you can use e.g. `//foo/normalize-space()` or `//foo/concat(.//bar, ';', .//baz)` or `string-join(//foo, ';')`.

With pure XPath 1.0 you would need to iterate in the host language (e.g. shell or XSLT or Java) and then concatenate in the host language.

Answer (score 1):

Concat will operate on the first node of a nodeset.
The following command adds more processing to take advantage of `xmllint` shell

```
echo -e "cd //h3[contains(text(),'Rodada')]/../following-sibling::div \n cat .//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')]/text() | .//div[contains(@class,'pull-left')]//img/@title | .//div[contains(@class,'pull-right')]//img/@title | .//strong/span/text() | .//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')][2]/text() \nbye\n" | \
xmllint --html --shell 2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html 2>/dev/null | \
tr -s ' ' | grep -v '^ *$' | \
gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="(\n -------){3,3}"; FS="\n -------\n"; OFS=";"} {if(NR>2) { print gensub(/\n/,"","g",$1),gensub(/title="([^"]+)"/,"\\1","g",$2),gensub(/title="([^"]+)"/,"\\1","g",$3),$4,$5}}'
```

Result

```
 S&aacute;b, 19/05/2012 21:00 - Jogo: 4 ; Figueirense - SC; N&aacute;utico - PE;2 x 1; Orlando Scarpelli - Florianopolis - SC
 Dom, 20/05/2012 16:00 - Jogo: 8 ; Ponte Preta - SP; Atl&eacute;tico - MG;0 x 1; Mois&eacute;s Lucarelli - Campinas - SP
 Dom, 20/05/2012 16:00 - Jogo: 5 ; Corinthians - SP; Fluminense - RJ;0 x 1; Pacaembu - Sao Paulo - SP
 Dom, 20/05/2012 16:00 - Jogo: 7 ; Botafogo - RJ; S&atilde;o Paulo - SP;4 x 2; Jo&atilde;o Havelange - Rio de Janeiro - RJ
 Dom, 20/05/2012 16:00 - Jogo: 6 ; Internacional - RS; Coritiba - PR;2 x 0; Beira-Rio - Porto Alegre - RS
 Dom, 20/05/2012 18:30 - Jogo: 1 ; Vasco da Gama - RJ; Gr&ecirc;mio - RS;2 x 1; S&atilde;o Janu&aacute;rio - Rio de Janeiro - RJ
 Dom, 20/05/2012 18:30 - Jogo: 2 ; Bahia - BA; Santos - SP;0 x 0; Pitua&ccedil;u - Salvador - BA

    .... (more records)
```

More clean up might be needed since field contain leading/trailing spaces.

Note: html needs to be converted to unix new lines

```
dos2unix 2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

Considering my alternatives that's my best solution so far.

```
´#!/bin/bash

 RODADAS=$(xmllint --html --xpath "//h3[contains(text(),'Rodada ')]/text()" $1 2>/dev/null)

 while read i
 do 
         for x in {1..10}
         do
               PREFIX="//h3[contains(text(), '$i')]/../following-sibling::div/ul/li[$x]";

               xmllint --html --xpath "normalize-space(concat($PREFIX//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')]/text(),';',$PREFIX//div[contains(@class,'pull-left')]//img/@title,';',$PREFIX//div[contains(@class,'pull-right')]//img/@title,';',$PREFIX//strong/span/text(),';',$PREFIX//span[contains(@class,'partida-desc')][2]/text()))" $1 2>/dev/null;
         done

done <<< "$RODADAS"´
```

Run:

```
./html-csv.sh 2012-campeonato-brasileiro.html
```

Result:

> Sáb, 01/12/2012 19:30 - Jogo: 373 ;Santos - SP;Palmeiras - SP;3 x 1; Vila Belmiro - Santos - SP
>
> Dom, 02/12/2012 17:00 - Jogo: 372 ;Fluminense - RJ;Vasco da Gama - RJ;1 x 2; João Havelange - Rio de Janeiro - RJ
>
> Dom, 02/12/2012 17:00 - Jogo: 374 ;São Paulo - SP;Corinthians - SP;3 x 1; Pacaembu - Sao Paulo - SP